# Beginner need help on learning Qt programming

Tags: programming-languages, programming-practices, qt, ebook

Thought of learning Qt. Need help from experienced ones out here. How should I begin. Some good books to refer. Some good tutorials to learn...

Edit: Also which is the good IDE available out there for Qt programming. One that gives inline help, auto completion,indentation... I am using Debian Lenny

Comment: C++ should be a good starting place.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427965/best-qt-ide This post gave me info about different IDE. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519291/qt-should-i-use-visual-studio-qt-creator-or-something-else http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476323/qt-creator-opinions-and-thoughts These two posts about qt ide give more insight into qt ide

Comment: As a beginner I found this one http://sector.ynet.sk/qt4-tutorial/my-first-qt-gui-application.html really helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131872494)  passed at one time through my hands. From what few days I had it, it seemed like a nice book; it's style of writing (explaining things) suited me very much. Your mileage may vary, but worth checking out nevertheless.

[image]

Also, two more advanced ones as suggested by ***Martin Beckett*** and ***Jestin Joy***.

[Advanced Qt Programming: Creating Great Software with C++ and Qt 4 (Prentice Hall Open Source Software Development Series)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321635906)

[image]

and [The Book of Qt 4: The Art of Building Qt Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593271476)
[image]

Comment: There's also an advanced programming with Qt follow up

Comment: Found another interesting book while seearching through net. "The Book of Qt4 - The Art of Building Qt Applications " by Daniel Molkentin.

Comment: @Martin Beckett, @Jestin Joy - Thanks guys. I added those as well.

Comment: Install Qt from Trolltak and check out samples folder. There are alot of samples. They will teach many more techniques that you cannot learn just by reading books.

Comment: Is **The Book of Qt 4: The Art of Building Qt Applications** an advanced book? No, I am really asking this question.

Answer (score 2):

I always found the tutorials on the Qt/Troll/Nokia site very helpful, and I know other people with the same experience.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter said QT tutorials & online documentation are always the places you should start. In addition you can also go to QT forums. Most importantly once you start coding you should download QT source code so that you can debug and explore it.